# If statement to allow single and multiple if options

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I have an If statement dependent on a choice made in a google form.  Everything currently works as needed BUT, the question choice allows them to choose ALL OPTIONS THAT APPLY.  If more than one option is chosen, the script fails.

How it currently works - person fills out form, script grabs info and inputs to a document, gives specified message based on choice from question (cif and message in script below), then emails the correct recipient (chosen in form).  It works beautifully if cif is submitted with one choice.

What do I add/edit to the script to allow for multiple choices, and therefore multiple messages input to the document, without having to write an If state for each scenario?

```
// Global variables 
var docTemplate = "1EoBcz0BK4R5hm-q5pR68xnQnR8DlR56XzjxRrgsu4uE";  // *** replace with your template ID ***
var docName     = "You got a High 5";

function onFormSubmit(e) { // add an onsubmit trigger
  
// Values come from the spreadsheet form  
   var observer = e.values[1]
   var teacher = e.values[2]
   var email = e.values[2]    
   var period = e.values[4] 
   var time = e.values[3]      
   var cif = e.values[5]    
   var comments = e.values[6]
   var message;
   if (cif == 'READ - Variety of texts') {
  message = 'read quote'
}
else if (cif == 'WRITE - Paper or electronic') {
  message = 'write quote'
}
else if (cif == 'THINK - Actively engaged students') {
  message = 'think quote'
}    
else if (cif == 'TALK - Purposeful discussion') {
  message = 'talk quote'
}        
else if (cif == 'MOVE - Students moving through class') {
  message = 'move quote'
}   
else if (cif == 'CIF not observed') {
  message = 'CIF not observed'
}  


// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
   var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
                .makeCopy(docName+' for '+teacher)
                .getId();
  
// Open the temporary document
   var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  
// Get the document’s body section
   var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  
// Replace place holder keys,  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyobserver', observer);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyperiod', period);
  copyBody.replaceText('keytime', time);
  copyBody.replaceText('keycif', cif);
  copyBody.replaceText('keycomments', comments);
  copyBody.replaceText('keymessage', message)


  
   var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"); 
   copyBody.replaceText('keyTodaysDate', todaysDate);
  
// Save and close the temporary document
   copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  
// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
   var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
  
// Attach PDF and send the email
   var subject = "High 5 - it matters.";
   var body    = "You got a High 5! See attached PDF. " +
                 "Please do not reply to this email.  You will be asked to supply a response thorugh a link within the attached PDF.  " +
                 "'Do all the good you can. By all the means you can. In all the ways you can. In all the places you can. At all the times you can. To all the people you can. As long as you ever can. -John Wesley'";
 
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
  // Delete temp file
   DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Kindly include a sample form and the error logs in your post above. Logs can be found at the Executions  tab of your script.

Comment: Error - Exception: Invalid argument: replacement
    at onFormSubmit(Code:54:12)

Sample form that gets filled out: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeknn_NiYaIVLobSeKPae97EVFUNef4wv8EtpcWTFtig0GsEA/viewform
spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rj-RWZSVO_ggFTmytWw3k9oUoaZ7zj5iG94khDQnqAM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The code you've posted above contains only 49 lines of code and the error code is on line 54.

Comment: I updated my full code. Line 54 is copyBody.replaceText('keymessage', message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple selected answer will return a comma separated values in form of string.

**For example:**

`e.values[5]` can have:

```
'READ - Variety of texts, WRITE - Paper or electronic, THINK - Actively engaged students, TALK - Purposeful discussion, MOVE - Students moving through class, CIF not observed'
```

in one single string and using `==` will not work since it has different content versus the string you are comparing to. This causes all of your if statements to fail because non of them matches the string. This leads to an undefined variable `message` which causes error on `replaceText()` function.

To fix the issue replace this line of code:

```
var message;
   if (cif == 'READ - Variety of texts') {
  message = 'read quote'
}
else if (cif == 'WRITE - Paper or electronic') {
  message = 'write quote'
}
else if (cif == 'THINK - Actively engaged students') {
  message = 'think quote'
}    
else if (cif == 'TALK - Purposeful discussion') {
  message = 'talk quote'
}        
else if (cif == 'MOVE - Students moving through class') {
  message = 'move quote'
}   
else if (cif == 'CIF not observed') {
  message = 'CIF not observed'
}
```

with:

```
  var message = [];
  
  if (cif.match('READ - Variety of texts')) {
    message.push('read quote');
  }
  
  if (cif.match('WRITE - Paper or electronic')) {
    message.push('write quote');
  }
  
  if (cif.match('THINK - Actively engaged students')) {
    message.push('think quote');
  }    
  
  if (cif.match('TALK - Purposeful discussion')) {
    message.push('talk quote');
  }        
  
  if (cif.match('MOVE - Students moving through class')) {
    message.push('move quote');
  }   
  
  if (cif.match('CIF not observed')) {
    message.push('CIF not observed')
  }
```

and in your

```
copyBody.replaceText('keymessage', message);
```

just add join function to make message a comma separated values when the content is more than 1:

```
copyBody.replaceText('keymessage', message.join(',');
```

### Example Usage:

**Multiple CIF:**

```
var cif = 'READ - Variety of texts, WRITE - Paper or electronic, THINK - Actively engaged students, TALK - Purposeful discussion, MOVE - Students moving through class, CIF not observed';
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Single CIF:**

```
var cif = 'WRITE - Paper or electronic';
```

**Output:**
[image]

### References

- [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Thank you!! You are amazing.  I really appreciate your help!